# Python - filter list from another other list with condition

Tags: python

```
list1 = ['/mnt/1m/a_pre.geojson','/mnt/2m/b_pre.geojson']
list2 = ['/mnt/1m/a_post.geojson']
```

I have multiple lists and I want to find all the elements of `list1` which do not have entry in `list2` with a filtering condition.
The condition is it should match `'m'` like `1m,2m`.. and name of `geojson` file excluding `'pre or post'` substring.

For in e.g. `list1 '/mnt/1m/a_pre.geojson'` is processed but `'/mnt/2m/b_pre.geojson'` is not so the output should have a list `['/mnt/2m/b_pre.geojson']`

I am using 2 for loops and then splitting the string which I am sure is not the only one and there might be easier way to do this.

```
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        pre_tile = i.split("/")[-1].split('_pre', 1)[0]
        post_tile = j.split("/")[-1].split('_post', 1)[0]
        if pre_tile == post_tile:
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have similar first part of the file paths. If so, you can try this:

```
list1 = ['/mnt/1m/a_pre.geojson','/mnt/2m/b_pre.geojson']
list2 = ['/mnt/1m/a_post.geojson']

res = [x for x in list1 if x[:7] not in [y[:7] for y in list2]]
```

res:

```
['/mnt/2m/b_pre.geojson']
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, using a regular expression to do this kind of string manipulation can be fast and easy.

Additionally, to do multiple member-tests in list2, it's more efficient to convert the list to a set.

```py
import re

list1 = ['/mnt/1m/a_pre.geojson', '/mnt/2m/b_pre.geojson']
list2 = ['/mnt/1m/a_post.geojson']

pattern = re.compile(r'(.*?/[0-9]m/.*?)_pre.geojson')
set2 = set(list2)
result = [
    m.string
    for m in map(pattern.fullmatch, list1)
    if m and f"{m[1]}_post.geojson" not in set2
]
print(result)
```